# edittext padding not reflect on actual device

Tags: android, android-edittext

I used startPadding for make some space.It reflect on AVD but when I test on actual device

It is not reflecting.

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/e_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

`android:padding  ="6dp"` : for giving padding from all direction (left, right,top,bottom).

or specify the direction using:

```
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only padding attribute it will affect padiing at left-right-top-bottom, syntax is below:

```
android:padding ="5dp"
```

or you can manually give padiing, like paddingLeft, right, top and botton with the syntax as below:

```
android:paddingLeft ="6dp"
android:paddingRight ="6dp"
android:paddingTop ="6dp"
android:paddingBottom ="6dp"
```